# Can't access AKS springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, azure-aks

I deployed a `springboot` application on a `pod` in `AKS`. The application deployed successfully but I can't seem to access it when I hit the external IP.

Below were my steps to deploy the application

```
kubectl run my-first-pod --image <<myimagename>>
kubectl expose pod my-first-pod  --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --name=my-first-service
```

Below is the output when I get the pod and service

```
kubectl get svc
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>          443/TCP        39m
my-first-service   LoadBalancer   10.0.184.166   20.221.43.253   80:31959/TCP   7s

NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-first-pod   1/1     Running   0          5m32s
```

When I do the same for an `nginx` application, It works fine. Getting this problem only with `springboot` application. I tried different ports but the same issue.

Comment: check - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-on-kubernetes

Comment: very useful..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by 2 steps

- `targetPort` should be whatever we exposed in docker
- add the targetPort in the `expose` command as shown below
  `kubectl expose pod my-first-pod  --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=8081 --name=my-first-service`